# Who are children of Vidura?

Tags: mahabharata, vidura

Vidura is a well-known character in Hinduism. He is the brother of Pandu, Dhritarashtra. He is an expert in analyzing dharma.

Dhritarashtra has 101 children and Pandu has five children.

Does Vidura have any children?

Answer (score 1):

"Meanwhile the son of the ocean-going Ganga heard that king Devaka had a daughter endued with youth and beauty and begotten upon a Sudra wife. Bringing her from her father's abode, Bhishma married her to Vidura of great wisdom. And Vidura begot upon her many children like unto himself in accomplishments.'"

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01115.htm